# EF Core: Get Records Containing Duplicates By Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database entity Foo that has the following properties:

```
public partial class Foo
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  etc...
}
```

I want to get the records where Type is one of a set of Types, and where there are two or more records for the same Name that meet this criteria.

The LINQ statement I have is:

```
var records = databaseContext.Foo
  .Where(r => listOfTypes.Contains(r.Type))
  .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g);
```

However, this gives an exception due to EF Core no longer falling back to client-side evaluation:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'g => g' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

I can force client-side evaluation by adding an .AsEnumerable() at the start of the LINQ statement, but this is horrendously slow and inefficient, taking over an hour to process the 20K+ records in my Foo table

How can I rewrite this so that it can be translated to SQL, or get this result some other way?

Comment: your LINQ query is right. So the issue might be related to another one, which I'm not sure about. I tried it with the same concept on LINQ pad. check out this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMG7w.png and this is the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io7WX.png

Comment: check out this SO question if it gives you any clues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898373/ef-core-linq-query-failing-due-to-limitation

Comment: To find duplicates you need analytic functions like ROW_NUMBER and raw SQL. That's not what ORMs like EF are about

Answer (score 1):

Please read this answer [LINQ to Database: how to group entities properly and GroupBy limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377955/linq-to-database-how-to-group-entities-properly-and-groupby-limitations). Your query is first - trying to select data from fields which are not a grouping keys.

Here you have to do additional join to the original table.

```
var baseQuery = databaseContext.Foo
   .Where(r => listOfTypes.Contains(r.Type));

var duplicateNames = baseQuery
  .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
  .Select(g => g.Key);

var records = baseQuery
  .Join(duplicateNames, f => f.Name, n => n, (f, n) => f);
```

Also this query also can be written by Window Functions, but they are not supported by vanilla EF.

Anyway leaving here fastest solution based on EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

```
var withCount = 
   from f in databaseContext.Foo
   where listOfTypes.Contains(f.Type)
   select new 
   {
       Record = f,
       Count = Sql.Ext.Count().Over().PartitionBy(f.Name).ToValue()
   };

// switch to alternative LINQ provider
withCount = withCount.ToLinqToDB();

var result = 
   from r in withCount
   where r.Count > 1
   select r.Record;
```

Comment: I've tried using your linq2dv.EntityFrameworkCore solution, but I get the exception "System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAsyncEnumerable' in type 'LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LinqToDBForEFQueryProvider`1' from assembly 'linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e41013125f9e410a' does not have an implementation."

Comment: Using your first set of LINQ queries gets me a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." exception.

Comment: @aforest-ccc, which version of EF Core do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the LINQ query w/o `GroupBy`, but with correlated subquery filter based on existence (actually non existence) of another record with the same property value, e.g.

```
// Base query with other filters applied
var baseQuery = databaseContext.Foo
    .Where(r => listOfTypes.Contains(r.Type);
// Actual query
var query = baseQuery
    .Where(r => !baseQuery.Any(f => f.Id != r.Id && f.Name == r.Name));
```

In case the entity really has no key (keyless?), the query can use correlated subquery `Count` based condition, but it won`t be so efficient as the above:

```
var query = baseQuery
    .Where(r => baseQuery.Count(f => f.Name == r.Name) > 1);
```

Comment: Foo doesn't have an Id field, so the final part of this query won't work.

Comment: But it has unique key (PK) which you haven't shown, isn't it? Otherwise it won't be an entity. Just use that property instead of `Id`. See the updated `Count` based solution in case the entity really has no key.